# Angular ui-router memory leaks strategy for Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, angular-ui-router

I started a Single Page Application in AngularJS. I'm using `ui-router`.

The app has the followings views:

- Login
- SignUp
- Home
- Profile

in an `index.html` File.

The problem is that I find a lot of places talking about the memory leaks that this is producing in the differents browsers and that we must be very careful about coding and memory.

So the questions is, if it is better to have the following structure:

index.html

- login
- signup

home.html

- home
- profile

It is obvious that the problem stills exists, but it is divided in two. It is this approach the better strategy? or I have to code like the first one and be more careful about memory leaks.

Comment: install batarang on chrome and inspect your code on efficiency https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek . The structure above does not matter.

Comment: the html structure of each view not matter? or the small amount of views no matter?

Comment: Not the structure will be the main problem, but the size, operations, api-calls, dependencies, .. Therefore both structures above are like for like.